# Java - versatile generic function param

Tags: java

So I am trying to consolidate and add a generic function to my flow to cut down on repetitive code.  I want to have something like this:

```
private <T> void cacheOrCall(T in) {
    // just want to execute any function passed here
    // in.execute? don't know how to fire these
}
```

The boiler plate is much larger, which is why I want to centralize this but I would like my function calls to look like:

```
cacheOrCall(mApi.getAlerts(mContext));
cacheOrCall(mApi.getSummary(mContext));
cacheOrCall(mApi.getHeadlines(mContext));
```

So my question is am I handling this generic function parameter correctly? And how do I execute a generic function I passed through as a parameter?

Thank you ahead of time

EDIT: Sorry the "in" function is an async API call.  The callback in my system is an event bus so I am not concerned about this function listening to anything.  I just simply want it to fire the api call I give it.  HOWEVER that can be a variety of DIFFERENT api calls.  I want this function to accept any api call function I give it and fire it off.  Hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: So you want something like `cacheOrCall(callback, ....` ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to achieve. Perhaps you should rewrite your question and state what the code is supposed to do,...

Comment: What didn't work when you tried it?

Comment: You don't need a type variable here, you can simply use `Object in`. Of course, you can use a more specific type than that if you need it, but there is nothing which requires it to use a type variable.

Comment: You need a callback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to pass in a function that is only called when necessary. One way would be to accept a Runnable:

```
private void cacheOrCall(Runnable in, ApiCommand command, String cacheKey) {
  //...
  in.run();
  //...
}
```

With Java 8+ you can then call that method with a lambda:

```
cacheOrCall(() -> mApi.getData(mContext), myCommand, myCacheKey);
```

With Java 7- you can pass an anonymous class:

```
Runnable in = new Runnable() { public void run() {
                                  mApi.getData(mContext);
                               }
                             };

cacheOrCall(in, myCommand, myCacheKey);
```

If you need a return value, you can use a `Callable<T>` instead of a `Runnable`:

```
private <T> void cacheOrCall(Callable<T> in, ApiCommand command, String cacheKey) {
  //...
  T result = in.call();
  //...
}
```

Comment: i guess that he needs a return type, but the idea is the same :)

Comment: callable throws exception :P

Comment: Sorry I added an edit, not only when necessary but be able to fire any dynamic api function I have that I send it.  for instance

cacheOrCall(mApi.getAlerts(mContext), myCommand, myCacheKey);

cacheOrCall(mApi.getSummary(mContext), myCommand, myCacheKey);

cacheOrCall(mApi.getHeadlines(mContext), myCommand, myCacheKey);

etc.

Comment: @AK824, I think assylias recommends to wrap those calls to API functions in a callable. The way your comment and question is typed, by way of Java Syntax, the API function would be invoked before cacheOrCall, which is not what you intend to do. I would highly recommend the posted solution, which is elegant and design-wise idiomatic.

Comment: @AK824 yes you can pass the method you like to `cacheOrCall` via the Runnable/Callable.